# Is it possible to initialize an object that automatically returns a seed of its own type?

Tags: c#, model, constructor

for example, I'm trying to initialize a new Person

```
var me = new Person();
```

but i'm just wondering if it's possible for that initialization to automatically return a seed?

I'm trying to add it to the constructor but I don't know how?

```
public class Person
{
   public Person Person(){ return ...}
}
```

well, that doesn't really work. Can anyone explain to me why it doesn't work and if there's another way to do this?

I can do object initialization, but I'm just wondering if this is possible??

Comment: What do you mean by "seed"?

Comment: Change the name of your function to `CreatePerson` and make it static?  That's called [the Factory (method) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).  Or just do something in your constructor.  No, you can't make `new` do anything but call the constructor (and base class constructors) and its (their) guts.  And the constructor won't return anything but the object you're constructing.  And no, you can't make it virtual.  You could use a separate (possibly abstract) factory class for that.

Comment: What's a seed, and what on earth are you trying to accomplish? The initialization of an object returns an object of that type, there's no need to make a constructor for that ..

Comment: @PVitt: means it automatically adds value to the variable (in this case "me") and populating the instantiated object.. ie: having Person.Name = "Joe" and etc... without me manually doing object initialization or what not... basically I want the model/class to create its own data right after I instantiate it..

Comment: @Jan: Just add that code to the constructor...

Comment: @AndreasCarlbom: i'm actually just curious..

Comment: @Jan sure, but it needs to know where to get the data from, assuming not all people are called `Joe`...

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: yeahh.. you're right actually. I forgot about that.

Comment: I didn't downvote you because I'm against this "sport", but it's because you wrote a badly explained question. The fact that you had to explain it in a comment and that the first half of the answers are "off the track" is an explanation enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> automatically adds value to the variable (in this case "me") and populating the instantiated object.. ie: having Person.Name = "Joe" and etc... without me manually doing object initialization or what not... basically I want the model/class to create its own data right after I instantiate it..

Just add implementation to the parameterless constructor:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Name = "Joe";
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When you call `var me = new Person();`, then `Name` will already be populated with `"Joe"`.

**More usages of constructors**

If you want to be able to customize the name more quickly, then you could add parameters to that constructor, or add a different constructor that takes parameters:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
        : this("Joe") // Calls the other constructor that takes a name...
    {
    }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var me = new Person(); // Joe
var you = new Person("You");
```

In the latest .Net, you can also use default values for these parameters to make your code shorter:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name = "Joe") // Will be "Joe" unless you say otherwise
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var me = new Person(); // Joe
var you = new Person("You");
```

Comment: exactly the right one i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

you can create a static method (factory)

```
var seededPerson = Person.CreateNew();

public class Person
{
  private Person() {}

  public static Person CreateNew()
  {
    return new Person() { Seed = 123; };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor initializes the *current* (newly allocated) instance; nothing more. It cannot return anything. It sounds like you just want a factory method:

```
public class Person
{
   public static Person Create(){ return ...}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person
{
    protected Person()
    {
    }

    public static Person BuildPerson(out int seed)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        seed = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(person);
        return person;
    }
}
```

You mean this? Using a "surrogate" constructor based on a static method?

or

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(out int seed)
    {
        seed = RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this);
    }
}
```

a constructor with an `out` argument?

As a sidenote, `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(object)` returns a pseudo unique id of an object. Pseudo unique because these numbers can be reused by .NET. A better "implementation" that always give unique ids would be:

```
public class Person
{
    private static int seed;

    public Person(out int seed)
    {
        seed = Interlocked.Increment(ref Person.seed);
    }
}
```

using the `Interlocked.Increment` to make the constructor thread safe.

Comment: using a `new Random()` like that is quite likely to lead to "all my random numbers are the same" issues when allocating in a loop. Just sayin'

Comment: I know... But I don't know what a seed is. And in reality it means "all the Person generated in the next few ms will give the same seed" :-) depending on the precision of `DateTime.Now/UtcNow`

Comment: @MarcGravell What would you think of the use of RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(this)? (remembering that numbers can be reused...)... Is this "letting the this escape the constructor" ok?

Comment: not exactly what I was asking, but those are some interesting points.. I'm definitely going to keep this answer in mind.

Comment: @xanatos that would probably do the job quite nicely - but then, if the requirement is randomisation, then in many ways it would be better to *pass in* a randomizer (makes it testable, for starters). An inventive solution, though